# Test multi-regression models and combine both after testing every model separately

Tags: hypothesis-testing, computational-statistics

I have two regression Models:
the first model with one dependent variable (Logarithm of income), one independent variable (Percentage of a proxy), and  four control variables with datatype (nominal, percentage, Logarithm, percentage)
the second model the same as the first model, but with different independent variable.

I need to know the required tests for each multi-regression model, and which test to combine the two models in one model.

thank you very much for any suggestion

Comment: This question is a little too vague.

Comment: I need to know the required tests to combine two multi-regression models with the same dependent variable and different independent variables, assume I have y=b0+b1x1+b2x2+b3x3+ei  and y=b0+b1S1+b2X2+b3x3+ei
so, I need to required tests for each model and required test to combine both in one model